# Tweeter API: How to write a query to search in User accounts?

Tags: api, tweets

I need to use Tweeter APIs to search User accounts. [The best API is in this link](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-search).

The Api example is as below:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q=soccer
```

where the `q` is the query. In the example, it selects the users who has the word "`soccer`" in their **profile's name**.

I need to write a query in a way that

1. It searches for all the users (regardless of their name, so I don't what `q` should be?)
2. The account is verified (attribute is `verified`)
3. The language is **Spanish** (attribute `status.lang`)
4. The `followers_count` is bigger than 10,000 (attribute `followers_count`)

I have tried the below request

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q=fake&verified=true&followers_count>10000&status.lang=de
```

But, it is not working

**Point:**

When you request an account, the response is as below. So, i guess, the query should be written based on this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 149450476,
        "id_str": "149450476",
        "name": "Nathan Fake",
        "screen_name": "nathanfake",
        "location": "UK",
        "description": "Official Nathan Fake Twitter.\nLIVE/DJ BOOKINGS:\nWorld excl. Americas: Mia Perelmuter - mia@lb-agency.net\nAmericas: Andres Montes - andres@surefireagency.com",
        "url": "Some url",
        "entities": {
            "url": {
                "urls": [
                    {
                        "url": "Some url",
                        "expanded_url": "http://nathanfake.com",
                        "display_url": "nathanfake.com",
                        "indices": [
                            0,
                            23
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "description": {
                "urls": []
            }
        },
        "protected": false,
        "followers_count": 19819,
        "friends_count": 641,
        "listed_count": 354,
        "created_at": "Sat May 29 09:27:07 +0000 2010",
        "favourites_count": 3619,
        "utc_offset": null,
        "time_zone": null,
        "geo_enabled": true,
        "verified": true,
        "statuses_count": 5006,
        "lang": null,
        "status": {
            "created_at": "Tue May 19 09:09:41 +0000 2020",
            "id": 1262671759951695874,
            "id_str": "1262671759951695874",
            "text": "@DasGiftBerlin they're a delicacy in galicia and portugal.. I wasn't that into it though",
            "truncated": false,
            "entities": {
                "hashtags": [],
                "symbols": [],
                "user_mentions": [
                    {
                        "screen_name": "DasGiftBerlin",
                        "name": "DasGift",
                        "id": 514663060,
                        "id_str": "514663060",
                        "indices": [
                            0,
                            14
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "urls": []
            },
            "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/android\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for Android</a>",
            "in_reply_to_status_id": 1262664168857092096,
            "in_reply_to_status_id_str": "1262664168857092096",
            "in_reply_to_user_id": 514663060,
            "in_reply_to_user_id_str": "514663060",
            "in_reply_to_screen_name": "DasGiftBerlin",
            "geo": null,
            "coordinates": null,
            "place": null,
            "contributors": null,
            "is_quote_status": false,
            "retweet_count": 0,
            "favorite_count": 0,
            "favorited": false,
            "retweeted": false,
            "lang": "en"
        },
        "contributors_enabled": false,
        "is_translator": false,
        "is_translation_enabled": false,
        "profile_background_color": "C0DEED",
        "profile_background_image_url": "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png",
        "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png",
        "profile_background_tile": true,
        "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1239999310181302276/qE-m2d2n_normal.jpg",
        "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1239999310181302276/qE-m2d2n_normal.jpg",
        "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/149450476/1584473432",
        "profile_link_color": "4A913C",
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "FFFFFF",
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
        "profile_text_color": "333333",
        "profile_use_background_image": true,
        "has_extended_profile": false,
        "default_profile": false,
        "default_profile_image": false,
        "following": false,
        "follow_request_sent": false,
        "notifications": false,
        "translator_type": "none"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the search for users (`/users/search` API endpoint) does not care about `lang:es` filter.

One approach to meet your requirement is to search for tweets (`/search/tweets.json` API endpoint https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets) with query `q` parameter set as `filter:verified` and `lang` parameter set to `es`. That will return tweets from verified users in Spanish.

From these tweet objects returned by Twitter API, you can select the user objects who have `follower_count` more than 10000. This customized processing is to be done by you in some programming language. Twitter API does not provide ready made methods to perform such complex queries.